# Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "BVLinearGradient"

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, npm

I have been working with the `react-native-gradient` and I am getting the following error regarding the package.

##### Error

```
Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "BVLinearGradient" was not found in the UIManager.

This error is located at:
    in BVLinearGradient (at react-native-linear-gradient/index.ios.js:54)
    in LinearGradient (at SignupLogin.js:46)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
    in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (at TouchableOpacity.js:224)
   .........    
    in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
    in DevAppContainer (at AppContainer.js:121)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:132)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:171:19 in handleException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
at node_modules/expo-error-recovery/build/ErrorRecovery.fx.js:12:21 in ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler$argument_0
at [native code]:null in flushedQueue
at [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue
```

##### Usage

```
...
import * as Animatable from "react-native-animatable";
import LinearGradient from "react-native-linear-gradient";
import MaterialIcons from "react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons";
import { useTheme } from "@react-navigation/native";


const SignupLogin = ({ navigation }) => {
  const { colors } = useTheme();
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      .....
        <View style={styles.button}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("sign-in")}>
            <LinearGradient
              colors={["#0831d4", "#0131ab"]}
              style={styles.signIn}
            >
              <Text style={styles.textSign}>Get started</Text>
              <MaterialIcons name="navigate-next" color="#fff" size={20} />
            </LinearGradient>
         .....
    </View>
  );
};


export default SignupLogin;
```

It is simple navigation between footer sign-in and sign-up menus and the `App.js` and the rest of the files are in the standard method of coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you're using windows & react-native cli (not expo):

**1-** in **android/settings.gradle**, check if

include ':react-native-linear-gradient'
project(':react-native-linear-gradient').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient/android')

exist .. if not, add them

---

**2-** in **android/app/build.gradle**, check if

```
implementation project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
```

exists in dependecies{ ... } .. if not, add it

---

**3-** in **android/app/src/main/java/com/{YOUR_APP_NAME}/MainApplication.java** , find

@Override
protected List getPackages() { ....}

Then replace the comment **// packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());**

with =>
**packages.add(new LinearGradientPackage());**

---

It worked for me .. Hope it works for you as well

Answer (score 1):

confirm you install [react-native-linear-gradient](https://github.com/react-native-linear-gradient/react-native-linear-gradient)

```js
yarn add react-native-linear-gradient
```

in ios confirm `ios/podfile` has this line

```js
pod 'BVLinearGradient', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient'
```

then run `pod install` in ios folder

Comment: Yes, I did. I am using a Linux system though. `npm install react-native-linear-gradient --save` and then link it using `react-native link react-native-linear-gradient`. The issue is in the ios files but I haven't used them in the run since I ran the app in Android.

Comment: I think you might not understand the issue. I am using a Linux machine and I built a React Native project using these libraries. The issue comes when I tried to run the application in the android simulator and then this error pops out. Dependencies are intact as I can see and I can't figure out what and where went wrong.

Comment: Maybe I have misunderstand, but I faced similar problem before in ios and i solved it with the above answer.

Comment: which platform you have the problem? `android or ios`?. and not important is it in linux or windows.

Comment: Sorry, I also mixed up few things. Yea, the `Podfile` has the link and the path you mentioned but still getting the error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237035/discussion-between-pulasthi-aberathne-and-ahmed-gaber).